# VB.NET - How To Change DataGridView Button Cell Image Based On Value? - VS 2022

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview called "dgvParts" on my form "frmPurOrd".  I am painting the several button cells with icon images successfully using the following vb.net code:

```
If ((Me.dgvParts.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "colWarranty") AndAlso (e.RowIndex >= 0)) Then
     e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.icons8_emptywarranty_14, CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Width) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_emptywarranty_14.Width) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.X)), CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Height) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_emptywarranty_14.Height) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.Y)))
     e.Handled = True
End If
```

This works great.  It paints the button image and properly centers the icon.

Where I have struggled is: I would like to change the "emptywarranty_14" image to a different image, "warranty_14" if the value of another cell in the same row is "true".  I am using column 16 as a true/false (checkbox) column in the datagridview.

The question is: how can I change the image in a button cell in EACH ROW, if a value in that row meets specific criteria?

I have, so far, tried using a For and Next statement as well as If statements.  They haven't worked.  The datagridview fails to properly paint at all, gltching out.  The only successes I've had is in painting the entire button column's cells with either the "warranty_14" or "emptywarranty_14" images.  I have not been able to get them to paint dependent upon each row's checkbox cell's value.

The image below is the result I get anytime I try an If/Then statement or a "a For i = 0 to dgvParts.RowCount - 1" statement.

[Glitched Out DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/541iA.png)

Edit: I have solved the original problem by moving the warranty value to the actual button column and adding "AndAlso e.Value = True" to my If statement as follows:

```
If ((Me.dgvParts.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "colSaved") AndAlso (e.RowIndex >= 0)) AndAlso e.Value = True Then
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.icons8_star_14, CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Width) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_star_14.Width) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.X)), CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Height) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_star_14.Height) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.Y)))
        e.Handled = True
    ElseIf ((Me.dgvParts.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "colSaved") AndAlso (e.RowIndex >= 0)) AndAlso e.Value = False Then
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.icons8_emptystar_14, CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Width) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_emptystar_14.Width) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.X)), CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Height) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_emptystar_14.Height) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.Y)))
        e.Handled = True
    End If

    If ((Me.dgvParts.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "colWarranty") AndAlso (e.RowIndex >= 0)) AndAlso e.Value = True Then
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.icons8_warranty_14, CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Width) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_warranty_14.Width) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.X)), CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Height) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_warranty_14.Height) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.Y)))
        e.Handled = True
    ElseIf ((Me.dgvParts.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "colWarranty") AndAlso (e.RowIndex >= 0)) AndAlso e.Value = False Then
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.icons8_emptywarranty_14, CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Width) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_emptywarranty_14.Width) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.X)), CInt((CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(((CDbl(e.CellBounds.Height) / 2) - (CDbl(My.Resources.icons8_emptywarranty_14.Height) / 1.375))))) + e.CellBounds.Y)))
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```

Now the problem I need to solve is how to hide the button text in the warranty column.  Each button has a value fo either True or False.  I am trying to figure out how to either hide the text (without changing the value) or change the forecolor of the text to blend with the backcolor.

I can use:

```
dgvParts.Columns(12).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
```

on form load, but it also changes the border color of the button.  Anyone know of a way to change only the text color on a button or hide it completely?

Comment: Rather than painting these images, have you considered using data bindings to switch out images?  Of course depends a lot on how you've defined the data source and connected it to the Grid in the first place

Comment: Hursey - It sounds like this may be worth exploring.  My data source is an Access accdb database, connected via OleDb and Visual Studio data bindings.  I wasn't aware that images could be data-bound.

Comment: You could be right about the image, but Visible properties can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up going in a completely different direction on this, using code found over at codeproject.com.  Thanks to Darryl Caillouet and his ["DataGridView Image Button Cell"](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27146/DataGridView-Image-Button-Cell) post.  Of course, I had to rewrite in vb.net and adapt it to my project, but here are the nuts and bolts, for anyone who wishes to make a datagridview more interactive:

```
Private Sub DataGridCol()
    Dim colSave As DataGridViewImageButtonSaveColumn = New DataGridViewImageButtonSaveColumn()
    Dim colInse As DataGridViewImageButtonInsertColumn = New DataGridViewImageButtonInsertColumn()
    colSave.Name = "colSaved"
    colSave.HeaderText = ""
    colInse.Name = "colInsert"
    colinse.HeaderText = ""
    dgvPastParts.Columns.Insert(10, colSave)
    dgvPastParts.Columns.Insert(11, colInse)
End Sub

Private _enabled As Boolean
Private _buttonState As PushButtonState
Protected _buttonImageEnabled As Image
Protected _buttonImageDisabled As Image

Private Sub SetGridButtonState(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal columnIndex As Integer, ByVal pushButtonState As PushButtonState)
    If (rowIndex > -1) AndAlso (columnIndex > -1) Then
        If (dgvPastParts.Columns(columnIndex).[GetType]().Equals(GetType(DataGridViewImageButtonSaveColumn))) OrElse (dgvPastParts.Columns(columnIndex).[GetType]().Equals(GetType(DataGridViewImageButtonInsertColumn))) Then
            Dim buttonCell As DataGridViewImageButtonCell = CType(dgv.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex), DataGridViewImageButtonCell)
            If buttonCell.Enabled Then
                buttonCell.ButtonState = pushButtonState
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public MustInherit Class DataGridViewImageButtonCell
    Inherits DataGridViewButtonCell
    Private _enabled As Boolean
    Private _buttonState As PushButtonState
    Protected _buttonImageEnabled As Image
    Protected _buttonImageDisabled As Image
    Private _buttonImageOffsetX As Integer
    Private _buttonImageOffsetY As Integer

    Protected Sub New()
        _enabled = False
        _buttonState = PushButtonState.Normal
        _buttonImageOffsetX = 6
        _buttonImageOffsetY = 2
        LoadImages()
    End Sub

    Public Property Enabled As Boolean
        Get
            Return _enabled
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _enabled = value
            _buttonState = If(value, PushButtonState.Normal, PushButtonState.Disabled)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ButtonState As PushButtonState
        Get
            Return _buttonState
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As PushButtonState)
            _buttonState = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ButtonImage As Image
        Get
            Select Case _buttonState
                Case PushButtonState.Disabled
                    Return _buttonImageDisabled
                Case PushButtonState.Normal
                    Return _buttonImageEnabled
                Case PushButtonState.Pressed
                    Return _buttonImageEnabled
                Case PushButtonState.[Default]
                    Return _buttonImageEnabled
                Case Else
                    Return _buttonImageEnabled
            End Select
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub Paint(ByVal graphics As Graphics, ByVal clipBounds As Rectangle, ByVal cellBounds As Rectangle, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal elementState As DataGridViewElementStates, ByVal value As Object, ByVal formattedValue As Object, ByVal errorText As String, ByVal cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, ByVal advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle, ByVal paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)
        If (paintParts And DataGridViewPaintParts.Background) = DataGridViewPaintParts.Background Then
            Dim cellBackground As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor)
            graphics.FillRectangle(cellBackground, cellBounds)
            cellBackground.Dispose()
        End If
        If (paintParts And DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) = DataGridViewPaintParts.Border Then
            PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle)
        End If
        Dim buttonArea As Rectangle = cellBounds
        Dim buttonAdjustment As Rectangle = BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle)
        buttonArea.X += buttonAdjustment.X
        buttonArea.Y += buttonAdjustment.Y
        buttonArea.Height -= buttonAdjustment.Height
        buttonArea.Width -= buttonAdjustment.Width
        Dim imageArea As Rectangle = New Rectangle(buttonArea.X + _buttonImageOffsetX, buttonArea.Y + _buttonImageOffsetY, 16, 16)
        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea, ButtonImage, imageArea, False, ButtonState)
    End Sub

    Public MustOverride Sub LoadImages()
End Class

Public Class DataGridViewImageButtonSaveColumn
    Inherits DataGridViewButtonColumn
    Public Sub New()
        Me.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewImageButtonSaveCell()
        Me.Width = 30
        Me.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.[False]
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DataGridViewImageButtonSaveCell
    Inherits DataGridViewImageButtonCell
    Public Overrides Sub LoadImages()
        _buttonImageEnabled = Image.FromStream(msSaved)
        _buttonImageDisabled = Image.FromStream(msNotSaved)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DataGridViewImageButtonInsertColumn
    Inherits DataGridViewButtonColumn

    Public Sub New()
        Me.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewImageButtonInsertCell()
        Me.Width = 30
        Me.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.[False]
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DataGridViewImageButtonInsertCell
    Inherits DataGridViewImageButtonCell

    Public Overrides Sub LoadImages()
        _buttonImageEnabled = Image.FromStream(msInsert)
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub dgvPastParts_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles dgvPastParts.DataBindingComplete
    For rowX As Integer = 0 To dgvPastParts.RowCount - 1
        If dgvPastParts.Rows(rowX).Cells("colPartSaved").Value = False Then
            CType(dgvPastParts.Rows(rowX).Cells("colSaved"), DataGridViewImageButtonSaveCell).ButtonState = PushButtonState.Disabled
        Else
            CType((dgvPastParts.Rows(rowX).Cells("colSaved")), DataGridViewImageButtonSaveCell).ButtonState = PushButtonState.Normal
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub dgvPastParts_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvPastParts.CellContentClick
    Dim view As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If ((view.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "colSaved") AndAlso (e.RowIndex >= 0)) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvPastParts.SelectedCells.Count - 1
            Dim rowIndex As Integer = dgvPastParts.SelectedCells(i).RowIndex
            If dgvPastParts.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("colPartSaved").Value = False Then
                dgvPastParts.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("colPartSaved").Value = True
                MsgBox("Part has been added to favorites.", vbOKOnly, "Part Added To Favorites")
            Else
                dgvPastParts.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("colPartSaved").Value = False
                MsgBox("Part has been removed from favorites.", vbOKOnly, "Part Removed From Favorites")
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

These functions are dependent on the following code (separate module) which contains the images stored as byte. You can translate an image into byte using the [Tomeko.net](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/file_to_hex.php?lang=en) file to hex converter.

```
Public iconSaved As Byte() = New Byte() {&H89, &H50, &H4E, &H47, &HD, &HA, &H1A, &HA, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HD, &H49, &H48, &H44, &H52, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HE, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HE, &H8, &H6, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H1F, &H48, &H2D, &HD1, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H9, &H70, &H48, &H59, &H73, &H0, &H0, &HB, &H13, &H0, &H0, &HB, &H13, &H1, &H0, &H9A, &H9C, &H18, &H0, &H0, &H1, &H28, &H49, &H44, &H41, &H54, &H78, &H9C, &HAD, &HCF, &HBD, &H4E, &HC2, &H50, &H1C, &H5, &H70, &H36, &HA4, &HED, &HBD, &H94, &H96, &HD6, &HC6, &HD9, &HC4, &HE8, &HE8, &HC7, &HB, &H30, &HB0, &H3A, &HF9, &H0, &H6E, &HBC, &H84, &HBE, &H83, &H4E, &HBA, &H28, &HB3, &HB3, &H26, &HA, &H28, &HF6, &HB, &H28, &H96, &H7E, &H29, &HAF, &H62, &H4, &HBD, &HF7, &H98, &H9A, &H46, &H21, &HDA, &H44, &H8C, &H67, &HFE, &HFF, &H72, &HCE, &HBF, &H50, &HF8, &HEF, &HE0, &HD1, &HD8, &H41, &H62, &H6C, &HFF, &H1, &HEA, &H57, &H88, &HF5, &HCB, &HC5, &H50, &HBC, &HB2, &H86, &H48, &H67, &H8, &H35, &H8E, &H91, &HB2, &HFE, &H7B, &H18, &H69, &HA7, &H8, &H35, &H20, &HA8, &H2, &HBE, &H72, &H92, &H7F, &HF8, &H64, &H1C, &H22, &HD1, &H9B, &H88, &HB4, &H16, &H22, &H6D, &H8C, &HB0, &H3A, &HC5, &H48, &H5, &H7C, &H15, &HF0, &H94, &H29, &H3C, &H79, &HCC, &H7A, &H72, &H8B, &HB9, &HB4, &H9, &H9B, &H1E, &H7C, &HC1, &H64, &H79, &H1F, &HB1, &HFE, &H8A, &H28, &H6B, &H49, &HD1, &H83, &H2, &HC, &H2B, &HE0, &H3, &H19, &HBC, &H5F, &H6, &H77, &H29, &H98, &H43, &HDE, &H60, &H4A, &H8D, &HF9, &HD6, &H40, &HDF, &H45, &HA0, &H3E, &H7F, &HB4, &HA4, &HC8, &HCB, &H50, &H2F, &H43, &H36, &H79, &H81, &H2D, &HED, &HFD, &H3C, &HD9, &H57, &H6B, &H18, &H66, &HA8, &H9F, &H21, &H87, &H82, &HDB, &H4, &H30, &HC5, &H5A, &HFE, &HAF, &H83, &HF2, &HD6, &HEC, &H34, &HEE, &H10, &H70, &H4B, &H2, &H37, &H45, &HA0, &H23, &H6C, &HE6, &H43, &HAF, &HD2, &HF8, &H9C, &H66, &H91, &H9, &H33, &HA5, &H9, &HBF, &H17, &HC1, &HBB, &H2, &HD0, &H29, &HCD, &HFF, &H36, &H1B, &HE6, &HD2, &HF3, &H74, &H1A, &HB3, &H49, &H1B, &H96, &HB4, &H81, &H2E, &H5D, &H65, &H77, &HC2, &H5, &HBF, &H2D, &H81, &HB5, &H97, &HCE, &HF2, &HA1, &H2D, &H1D, &HC3, &H14, &HEA, &HDF, &H96, &HDC, &H14, &HEB, &HEC, &HBA, &H78, &H94, &HB, &H17, &HC9, &H3B, &H12, &HCE, &HD4, &HB5, &H6A, &H55, &H50, &H24, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H49, &H45, &H4E, &H44, &HAE, &H42, &H60, &H82}
Public msSaved As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(iconSaved)

Public iconNotSaved As Byte() = New Byte() {&H89, &H50, &H4E, &H47, &HD, &HA, &H1A, &HA, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HD, &H49, &H48, &H44, &H52, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HE, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HE, &H8, &H6, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H1F, &H48, &H2D, &HD1, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H9, &H70, &H48, &H59, &H73, &H0, &H0, &HB, &H13, &H0, &H0, &HB, &H13, &H1, &H0, &H9A, &H9C, &H18, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HA8, &H49, &H44, &H41, &H54, &H78, &H9C, &HB5, &HD0, &H31, &H6A, &H2, &H50, &H10, &H45, &HD1, &H53, &HD8, &H66, &H11, &H16, &H16, &H49, &HA5, &HD8, &HDA, &HD8, &HC6, &HD2, &H46, &H10, &HEC, &HEC, &HDC, &H82, &H2B, &HD0, &H1D, &H58, &HB9, &H1, &HD, &H64, &H13, &HA2, &HBD, &H20, &H82, &HA5, &HEB, &H90, &H81, &H51, &H44, &HFD, &HA2, &H84, &H5C, &H78, &H30, &HDC, &H37, &H3, &H9F, &HCF, &H3F, &H50, &HCF, &HBC, &HCD, &H2A, &HF3, &H16, &H1D, &H2C, &HF1, &H83, &HEF, &H57, &HE, &H3E, &HD0, &HC4, &H1A, &H8D, &HCC, &H26, &H5D, &H74, &H77, &H4C, &H70, &HC0, &H16, &HB, &H8C, &HAE, &HBA, &H51, &HBA, &H6D, &HEE, &HC4, &HEE, &H85, &H16, &HF6, &HF8, &H7C, &HF2, &H9A, &H1A, &H76, &H68, &HDF, &H16, &HCF, &H8E, &H6B, &HA5, &HA3, &H33, &H3, &HCC, &H1E, &HF8, &H59, &H76, &H45, &H86, &H18, &HE7, &H5C, &HC9, &H4, &HE1, &HA2, &H2B, &H32, &H45, &HF, &HFD, &HFC, &H8C, &H48, &HCC, &HE1, &HA2, &H2B, &HF2, &H8B, &H23, &HE6, &HA8, &H66, &H62, &HE, &H17, &H5D, &H91, &H2E, &HBE, &H1E, &HF8, &H70, &HD1, &HFD, &H9D, &H13, &H7D, &H40, &H1F, &HA4, &H16, &HA6, &H69, &HCF, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H49, &H45, &H4E, &H44, &HAE, &H42, &H60, &H82}
Public msNotSaved As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(iconNotSaved)

Public iconInsert As Byte() = New Byte() {&H89, &H50, &H4E, &H47, &HD, &HA, &H1A, &HA, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HD, &H49, &H48, &H44, &H52, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HE, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HE, &H8, &H6, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H1F, &H48, &H2D, &HD1, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H9, &H70, &H48, &H59, &H73, &H0, &H0, &HB, &H13, &H0, &H0, &HB, &H13, &H1, &H0, &H9A, &H9C, &H18, &H0, &H0, &H1, &H8D, &H49, &H44, &H41, &H54, &H78, &H9C, &HAD, &HD2, &H5F, &H2F, &H42, &H1, &H0, &H5, &HF0, &HDE, &HFA, &H6, &H56, &H1A, &HD1, &H9F, &H85, &H21, &H42, &H4F, &H94, &H27, &HF3, &HE2, &HC5, &H66, &HF3, &H25, &H6C, &HC6, &HD6, &HA6, &HB1, &H5D, &HA3, &H99, &H2D, &HF, &H8D, &HD1, &HD4, &HCD, &HAD, &H4C, &H1B, &H23, &H4F, &H3E, &H81, &H15, &H8D, &H59, &HE9, &H8F, &H52, &HA9, &H28, &HDD, &HFE, &HBD, &HF6, &H42, &HC7, &H6E, &H74, &HCB, &H1A, &H2F, &H9C, &HF7, &HDF, &H76, &H76, &H76, &H38, &H9C, &HFF, &H4A, &H87, &H2E, &HA2, &H6E, &H27, &HC2, &H64, &HDB, &H4A, &HC8, &H2D, &HD0, &H6, &H5C, &H3C, &H8D, &H9F, &HE4, &H2D, &H7A, &H55, &H3F, &H2, &H89, &H21, &HC2, &H95, &H6E, &HC5, &H6C, &HE2, &HCD, &H28, &H3A, &H75, &H8F, &H10, &HAE, &H86, &HD1, &HB6, &H12, &H82, &H40, &H1B, &H4, &H5F, &HE3, &H47, &HCB, &H82, &H8F, &H92, &HCC, &H45, &HB8, &H4D, &H50, &HB6, &H9D, &HB4, &HC9, &HC, &H9, &H48, &HB7, &HE2, &HF8, &HD, &H73, &H1A, &HD3, &H4B, &HA6, &HD4, &H3D, &HC6, &H67, &H74, &HED, &H24, &H31, &H45, &HC5, &H31, &HB1, &H1F, &HC5, &HF8, &H6E, &H14, &HDD, &H1B, &HE1, &H26, &HCC, &H9F, &HF7, &H8E, &HB1, &HB0, &H8F, &HCA, &H90, &HBD, &HE6, &H17, &H30, &HF8, &HD4, &H57, &HC0, &HBE, &H3B, &HB, &HCA, &H93, &HC7, &H53, &HA1, &H8C, &H59, &H6B, &H1C, &H42, &HE2, &H81, &HC5, &H3C, &H8D, &HDF, &HC4, &HC2, &H1, &H7B, &HF6, &HBA, &H9F, &HCA, &H80, &HC1, &HA7, &HF7, &H45, &H98, &HAE, &H68, &H50, &H37, &H5, &H30, &H79, &HAF, &H0, &H16, &H77, &HE, &H22, &H22, &H58, &HC5, &HAD, &H4B, &H1, &H37, &HB, &H7, &H1D, &HF4, &HD5, &HC0, &H61, &H16, &HC, &H3E, &HF3, &H17, &H61, &HF2, &HD0, &HB0, &HDE, &H7E, &HC2, &HB7, &HA, &HB0, &H77, &H49, &H43, &HBC, &HFE, &H55, &H7B, &H39, &HE4, &H62, &HE1, &HD0, &H71, &H9E, &H54, &H38, &H68, &H30, &HD8, &H19, &H2C, &HC1, &H7C, &H93, &H83, &HED, &HAE, &H88, &H50, &HAE, &H8C, &HE9, &HC3, &H24, &HA4, &HFA, &H58, &H7D, &H30, &H22, &H5C, &HAF, &H3A, &H72, &H5E, &H52, &HD, &H9F, &HE4, &HC1, &HE0, &H19, &H67, &H1A, &H53, &HC7, &H29, &H4C, &H1E, &H3D, &H43, &H6E, &H4C, &H56, &H7, &H6B, &H5C, &H5B, &HB4, &H16, &H1B, &HFD, &HB6, &HAC, &HD2, &H59, &HA4, &H6A, &HB8, &H56, &HBB, &H36, &H18, &H8B, &HF5, &H71, &H4B, &HF3, &H1, &H2E, &HC0, &HFD, &H1D, &H27, &H2C, &HCC, &H49, &H7E, &H7C, &H90, &HD2, &H59, &H1A, &H1B, &H3E, &HC9, &H9B, &H15, &HE, &HDA, &H25, &HB7, &HBF, &HBA, &HFA, &HF, &H32, &HA6, &H1E, &H32, &HFD, &HBD, &HDE, &H5F, &HF2, &H1, &H77, &H7B, &H42, &HA0, &H24, &HAC, &H48, &HE1, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H49, &H45, &H4E, &H44, &HAE, &H42, &H60, &H82}
Public msInsert As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(iconInsert)
```

Answer (score 0):

After filling your datagridview, simply enumerate rows and get cells in each of them.
example :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvParts.Rows 'enumerate rows
            'get/test/modify cells by colum name or index
            If row.Cells(16).Value = True Then 'test cell column 16
                Dim myCell As DataGridViewCell = row.Cells("colWarranty") 'get cell in column colWarranty
                myCell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red 'modify cell as you need (backcolor for example)
            End If
        Next row
    End Sub
```

Comment: tuyau2poil - Thanks for the input.  Sadly, row enumeration results in the datagridview failing to render.  It, for some reason, becomes a jumbled mess.  I attempted enumeration in the cell painting process, and also tested your code to simply change the cell's background color and the dgv fails to render.

Comment: can you post full form code ? I will try it in my visual studio.